# disabling divs based on certain situations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have inputs which are disabled depending on whether a certain object has a length greater than zero.

```
<input ng-disabled="(entities[1].itemAttrs.length > 0)?true:false" type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-disabled="formReadOnly" data-ng-model="item[item.fields[51].name]" data-ng-keyup="comboBoxTherOptions(2, 327, item[item.fields[51].name], 'searchTherOptions')" />
```

Here:

```
ng-disabled="(entities[1].itemAttrs.length > 0)?true:false"
```

I want to add it to my div's which, have a lot of directives that have been built over the years by people.

```
<div ng-disabled="(entities[1].itemAttrs.length > 0)?true:false" data-strat-form-control data-field-display-id="1" data-vmformreadonly="formReadOnly" data-show-tool-tip="showTEoolTip(item.fields[5].htmlName)" data-strat-model="item" data-field="item.fields[5]"></div>
```

However, it has no effect, unlike the input fields.

How can I disable these divs under the same circumstances as my inputs?

Comment: All ng-disabled does is set an attribute marking the area as disabled. You would have to add functionality for disabling the div element. Browsers have built in support for disabled elements such as input, select, textarea, but not divs

Comment: @ITDerrickH Can you show how you would do that?

Comment: One of these answers might be able to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561144/disabling-an-entire-div-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my code it will work as acepted

```
enter code here
```

var xx = angular.module('ap', []).controller('c', function ($scope) {

        $scope.a = 0;

    });

0)?true:false" type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" ng-model="a" />

enter code here

Answer (score 0):

`ng-disabled` simply add/remove a disabled attribute to your dom element. But, this attribute is ready for all : [w3scool description](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp).

The alternative way consists of using `ng-class` and look through the world wide web on how-to make my div disabled (without any angularjs context) => [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365751/css-how-to-make-inactive-content-inside-div)